# Why Request timeout occurs when a request is attempted beyond the "Ktor HttpClient(CIO) maxConnectionsCount" or "maxConnectionsPerRoute" value

Tags: android, connection, max, httpclient, ktor

```
"KtorBase2.kt"
open class KtorBase2()
{
    private val _httpClient: HttpClient
    val httpClient get() = _httpClient

    init {
        _httpClient = createHttpClient()
    }

    private fun createHttpClient(): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(CIO) {
            engine {
                // this: CIOEngineConfig
                // I don't know why Request timeout occurs when I try to request beyond the maxConnectionsCount or maxConnectionsPerRoute values.
                maxConnectionsCount = 12 // system default=1000
                endpoint {
                    // this: EndpointConfig
                    maxConnectionsPerRoute = 100 // system default=100
                    pipelineMaxSize = 20 // system default=20
                    keepAliveTime = 5000 // system default=5000
                    connectTimeout = 5000 // system default=5000
                    connectAttempts = 1 // system default=1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

"HomeDataAccesss.kt"
{
    suspend fun getTestHtml(ktorBase2: KtorBase2) : String {
        val response: HttpResponse =  ktorBase2.httpClient.get("http://ap2.shinwonsoft.com/test/test.html") {
        }

        return response.body()
    }
}

"HomeViewModel.kt"
{
    fun reqTestHtml(ktorBase2: KtorBase2, testCountForManyRequest: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val str = HomeDataAccess.getTestHtml(ktorBase2)
            Log.d(logTag, "### reqTestHtml::html=$str, testCountForManyRequest=$testCountForManyRequest")
        }
    }
}

"HomeFragment.kt"
class HomeFragment: Fragemnt {
    private var _testCountForManyRequest: Int = 0
    private val _testKtorForManyRequest: KtorBase2 = KtorBase2(URLProtocol.HTTP)

    ...

    private fun initViewEventListener() {
        binding.textHome.setOnClickListener {
            (it as TextView).text = "Home fragemnt: ${++_testCountForManyRequest}"

            _homeViewModel.reqTestHtml(_testKtorForManyRequest, _testCountForManyRequest)
        }
    }
}

"console log"
19:05:33.635 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=1
19:06:52.385 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=2
19:07:28.888 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=3
19:07:29.653 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=4
19:07:30.231 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=5
19:07:30.726 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=6
19:07:31.266 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=7
19:07:32.122 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=8
19:07:33.303 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=9
19:11:11.393 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=10
19:11:30.733 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=11
19:11:36.508 HE_HomeViewModel         D  ### reqTestHtml::html=test..., testCountForManyRequest=12
19:11:48.195 android.ha...mpl.ranchu  D  threadLoop: entering standby, frames: 2233440
--------- beginning of crash
19:11:50.138 StatusBarIconController  D  ignoring old pipeline callbacks, because the new mobile icons are enabled
19:11:50.167 AndroidRuntime           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kr.co.heavyequipment, PID: 4914
    io.ktor.client.network.sockets.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect timeout has expired [url=http://ap2.shinwonsoft.com/test/test.html, connect_timeout=unknown ms]
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpTimeoutKt.ConnectTimeoutException(HttpTimeout.kt:213)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpTimeoutKt.ConnectTimeoutException$default(HttpTimeout.kt:210)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.Endpoint.getTimeoutException(Endpoint.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.Endpoint.connect(Endpoint.kt:257)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.Endpoint.access$connect(Endpoint.kt:25)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.Endpoint$connect$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@5f7479, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
19:11:50.173 DropBoxManagerService    I  add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
19:11:50.175 ActivityTaskManager      W    Force finishing activity kr.co.he/.ui.main.MainActivity
```

I don't know why Request timeout occurs when a request is attempted beyond the "Ktor HttpClient(CIO) maxConnectionsCount" or "maxConnectionsPerRoute" values.

Requests are successful up to the number of "maxConnectionsCount=12" set in "Ktor::HttpClient::engine", but a timeout error occurs for the 13th request.

If you set "maxConnectionsCount=12, maxConnectionsPerRoute=10", a timeout error occurs on the 11th request.

Is the CIO using it the wrong way? I hope you can help.

(Even if you increase the max value infinitely, does it not put a load on the Android terminal?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your exact problem. You can install the `HttpTimeout` plugin to increase the connection timeout via the `connectTimeoutMillis` property.

Comment: I set “timeout install” as shown below.
I get the same error.

install(HttpTimeout) {
    if (isBuildConfigDebug) { // BuildConfig.DEBUG
        requestTimeoutMillis = 30_000L
        connectTimeoutMillis = 30_000L
        socketTimeoutMillis = 30_000L
    } else {
        requestTimeoutMillis = 10_000L
        connectTimeoutMillis = 10_000L
        socketTimeoutMillis = 10_000L
    }
}

Comment: Because of the above error, I tested with Apache5.
There was no error when the request test was attempted 3500 times using Apache5 instead of CIO.

Comment: my project build.gradle(app); def ktor_version = '2.3.5'
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version");
    //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version");
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-apache5:$ktor_version");
    //implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-java:$ktor_version");
    // Ktor-Serialization;
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version");
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version");
    // Ktor Auth.;
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktor_version");

Comment: Can you file an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR) with a minimal self-contained code snippet to reproduce the issue?